# Finding if a single rgb value falls within a threshold of any rgb value in an array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, threshold

I would appreciate some advice on creating a function to compare a single RGB value against an array of RGB values and determine if it falls within a threshold. This is done in vanilla javascript using the HTML5 canvas element.

My first attempt:

```
var colorArray = [  //rgb values to search through
[212, 35, 96],
[200, 200, 150],
[100, 100, 75]
];

var threshold = 15;   //the threshold

//Given a canvas with an image drawn on it
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // get the canvas pixel data

for(var row = 0; row < canvas.height; row++){   //stepping through the pixels

    for (var col = 0, index = 0, colorTotal = 0; col < canvas.width; col++){
        
        index = (col + (row * canvas.width)) * 4;
        colorTotal = pixelData.data[index] + pixelData.data[index + 1] + pixelData.data[index + 2];  //add the rgb values of the current pixel

        for(var i = 0, pixelColorTotal = 0, result = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){   //stepping through the colorArray

            pixelColorTotal = colorArray[i] [0] + colorArray[i] [1] + colorArray[i] [2];  //add the rgb values of the current array element
            result = Math.abs(colorTotal - pixelColorTotal);  //find the difference between the color totals

            if(result < threshold){
               //..do something we've breached the threshold
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That does not work so well because for example: [255, 0, 50] and [50, 255, 0] are not even close to the same color yet they would trip the threshold.

My 2nd attempt:

```
var colorArray = [  //rgb values to search through
[212, 35, 96],
[200, 200, 150],
[100, 100, 75]
];

var threshold = 15;   //the threshold

//Given a canvas with an image drawn on it
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // get the canvas pixel data

for(var row = 0; row < canvas.height; row++){   //stepping through the pixels

    for (var col = 0, index = 0; col < canvas.width; col++){
        
        index = (col + (row * canvas.width)) * 4;

        for(var i = 0, result = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){   //stepping through the colorArray

            result = Math.abs(pixelData.data[index] - colorArray[i] [0]);   //load red difference
            if(result >= threshold){       //check the red channel to see if it exceeds threshold

                result = Math.abs(pixelData.data[index + 1] - colorArray[i] [1]);   //load green difference
                if(result >= threshold){       //check the green channel to see if it exceeds threshold

                     result = Math.abs(pixelData.data[index + 2] - colorArray[i] [2]);   //load blue difference
                     if(result >= threshold){       //check the green channel to see if it exceeds threshold

                         //do something we have passed all the threshold checks

                     }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is better but very inefficient.

Are there any better ideas out there? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, so let me know if I'm going in the wrong direction.

```
function withinThreshold(colorArr, inputArr, threshold){
    let maxThreshold = threshold;
    let minThreshold = threshold * -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i++){
        let rDiff = colorArr[i][0] - inputArr[0];
        let gDiff = colorArr[i][1] - inputArr[1];
        let bDiff = colorArr[i][2] - inputArr[2];
        if(rDiff > minThreshold && rDiff < maxThreshold &&
           gDiff > minThreshold && gDiff < maxThreshold &&
           bDiff > minThreshold && gDiff < maxThreshold){
             return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

var colorArray = [  //rgb values to search through
    [212, 35, 96],
    [200, 200, 150],
    [100, 100, 75]
];
var threshold = 15;

for(var row = 0; row < canvas.height; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col < canvas.width; col++){
        let pixel = ctx.getImageData(row, col, 1, 1);
        let match = withinThreshold(colorArray, pixel, threshold);
        if(match === -1){
            console.log('no match found');
        }else{
            console.log('match found! index:',match);
        }
        // I made it like indexOf, it will return the matching index of colorArr.
        // You can simplify it like this:
        /*
            if(match > -1){
                console.log('match found');
            }
        */
    }
}
```

Also don't forget that getImageData will most likely return 4 digit array [r,g,b,a], unless you changed the settings to not allow alpha.

Also I made it so it individually grabs the pixel data it needs. This way in the future you can refine it down to a specific location without having the check everything.  Simply by changing the **row** and **canvas.width** to 10 and 20.  This way you can save processing for only the changed area. You can also do it with **col** and **canvas.height** to shrink it down even more.

I made a few canvas rendering engines, so I've ran into performance issues and had to deal with a lot of optimising.

Comment: I calculated the difference like you did. Much faster. My use of Math.abs was slowing it down I think.
As it is, the user selects an active area of a image. The colorArray var is populated with the prominent colors of this area. The colorArray is not compared to the image itself but compared to a result from processing the image. Within the result I use the alpha channel to flag if pixels will be further processed or not. The code we have discussed here is one of the methods I may use to filter the first level result with.
It's fast enough to experiment with now. Thanks for posting

Comment: @lucyPa, so was it answered?